# For given $p$, a regular mapping $F:M \to N$ of surfaces can be diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

Want to show :

For given point $p$ of M, a regular mapping $F:M \to N$ of surfaces has a neighborhood $U$ such that $F|_{U}$ is a diffeomorphism of $U$ onto a neighborhood of $F(p)$ in N.

I learned that

$f$ is diffeomorphism $\iff$ $f^{-1}$ is differentiable

That regular mapping $f$: $M$ onto $N$ is one-to-one implies that $f$ is diffeomorphism.

I want to show that there exists open set $U$ containing $p$ such that $F|_{U}$ is one-to-one beacuse we know that $F$ is regular.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the Euclidean case. If you have a $C^1$ smooth map $f:V\to W$ between open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, and $Df(p)$ is invertible,  can you conclude that $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $f:U\to f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism? (Hint: Inverse function theorem).

The general case follows from Euclidean + chain rule. Indeed, by definition of a smooth surface, $p$ has  a neighborhood  that is diffeomorphic to an open subset of  $\mathbb R^2$. And $f(p)$ has such a neighborhood. Composing your regular map with these diffeomorphisms reduces the problem to the preceding paragraph.